# getting error code "cannot GET /admin/add-product"

Tags: node.js, express

this is my second question here on stack overflow.

I am currently doing a course on udemy on node.js from "0" to "expert", now keep in mind my carrer as a developer focuses on front-end not back-end or even middle-ware in particular, this is just a course that I payed for because I feel it complements very well my carrer and the topic is of high interest to me.

Now with the problem... We started working with pug and handlebars, previously we were working with express.js. Every since I installed pug and translated one of the pages from the webpage we are building on the course from vanilla html to pug the server is throwing the "cannot GET /admin/add-product". Now I understand this error is based on the logic end of everything cause the server clearly states it's not able to obtain the specific route where the "add-product.html" code is located. Where i'm confused is that the code is the same the teacher has, and in the videos this error won't show up, I tried to put a question as a comment on the course's comment section but it hasn't been answered and this is keeping me from continuing with the material. It would be of great value if someone here would look over the code (which I will be posting in this question) and gives me a hand cause at this point i'm completely lost.

Thanks you very much stack overflow community

Project code:

app.js:

```
const path = require('path');

const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', 'views');

const adminData = require('./routes/admin');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/user');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/admin', adminData.routes);
app.use(userRoutes);

// app.use((res, req, next) => {
//     res.status(404).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views', ''));
// });

const server= http.createServer(app);

server.listen(3000);
```

---

admin.js:

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const rootDir = require('../util/path');

const router = express.Router();

const products = [];

router.get('/admin', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(rootDir, 'views', 'add-product.html'));
});

router.post('/admin', (req, res, next) => {
    products.push({title: req.body.title})
    res.redirect('/');
});

exports.routes = router;
exports.products = products;
```

---

user.js:

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const rootDir = require('../util/path');

const adminData = require('./admin');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const products = adminData.products;
    res.render('shop', {prods: products, docTitle: 'Shop'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

---

path.js:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = path.dirname(require.main.filename);
```

---

add-product.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Add product page</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/product.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="main-header__nav">
                <ul class="main-header__item-list">
                    <li class="main-header__item"><a class="active" href="/">SHOP PAGE</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>

        <main>
            <form class="product-form" action="/admin/add-product" method="POST">
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title">
                </div>

                <button type="submit">ADD PRODUCT</button>
            </form>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

shop.pug:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
html(lang="en")
    head
        meta(charset="UTF-8")
        meta(name="viewport", content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0")
        meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="ie=edge")
        title #{docTitle} 
        link(rel="Stylesheet", href="/css/main.css")
        link(rel="Stylesheet", href="/css/products.css")
    body
        header.main-header
            nav.main-header__nav
                ul.main-header__item-list
                    li.main-header__item
                        a.active(href="/") Shop
                    li.main-header__item
                        a(href="/admin/add-product") Add Product

        main
            .grid
                each product in prods
                    article.card.product-item
                        header.card__header
                            h1.product__title #{product.title}
                        .card__image
                            img( src="https://www.vecteezy.com/photo/1224769-open-book-on-dark-background", alt=" a book ")
                        .card__content 
                            h2.product__price $19.99
                            p.product__description A ver interesting book about so many even more intersting things! 
                        .card__actions 
                            button.btn Add to Cart
```

Thanks for your time everyone

Comment: Do you have it in a git repo?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, I guess the path of line 11 and 15 in `admin.js` should be `'/add-product'` instead of `'/admin'`. i.e.

```
router.get('/add-product', (req, res, next) => {
```

In your code, the only route under `/admin` is `/admin/admin` with method `GET` or `POST`. You can try GET `/admin/admin` and see if it's the expected result. if true, that indicates you wrote a wrong path in line 11 and 15 in `admin.js`

If you want to GET `/admin/add-product`, you'll need a route in `admin.js` which path is `/add-product`, since all request with a path begins with `/admin` are handled by `adminData.routes` at line 18 in `app.js`